# If $\tan x + \tan y = 4$ and $\cos x + \cos y = 1/5$, find $\tan(x+y)$.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> If $\tan x + \tan y = 4$ and $\cos x + \cos y = 1/5$, find $\tan(x+y)$.

Well, from the first condition, we get
$$\tan x + \tan y = \frac{\sin(x+y)}{\cos x \cos y}=4 \implies \sin(x+y)=4\cos x \cos y$$
Then,
$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}=\frac{4}{1-\frac{\sin x \cos y}{\cos x \cos y}}=\frac{4}{1-\frac{4\sin x \cos y}{\sin(x+y)}}$$
But in this way, I couldn't get use of the second condition. Actually, I squared the first condition and replaced $\tan^2$ with $\sec^2-1$. Then, squared the second condition to find something useful about $\sec^2$'s. Yet, nothing that works.

Therefore, started substituting $\cos x = a$ and $\cos y = b$ to get

$$
\begin{cases}
\cfrac{\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a} + \cfrac{\pm\sqrt{1-b^2}}{b} = 4 \\
a + b = \cfrac{1}{5}
\end{cases}
$$
Nonetheless, this system doesn't seem to be as easy as this problem might be given as a multiple-choice problem (2-3 minutes for solving).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I don't like how adding a `>` sign increases the transparency of text.

Comment: The first equation you wrote should be $\displaystyle \frac{\pm \sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}+\frac{\pm \sqrt{1-b^2}}{b}=4$ because what you have written would mean that both $\sin x$ and $\cos x $ are positive...which is not necessary.

Comment: @ABCD Yes, you are right. Then, becomes even more complicated :)

Comment: I get numerically three different solutions

Comment: @enzotib But the question is to evaluate the solutions by hand...

Comment: @ABCD in fact it was not an answer, only an indication, if I'm not wrong, that there is not a unique solution

Comment: @VIVID, what was the source of the problem?

Comment: @ABCD My friend gave me this. And I also wonder if it's not ill-posed / wrong...

Comment: It might be the case because as @enzotib suggested, there are 3 different answers...

Comment: @ABCD What is wrong with 3 solutions?

Comment: If it's a multiple choice problem, then for each proposed solution $s$ calculate $\tan x \tan y=1-\frac{4}{s}$, given sum and product of tangents, find values $t_1,t_2$, then $\cos\arctan t_1+\cos\arctan t_2$ should give $1/5$ only for the right solution

Comment: @VIVID a multiple choice test has usually only a single correct result

Comment: @enzotib I'm sorry not to have the choices, but there might be a triplet of solutions in each choice. Could you show me your solutions, please?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is a misprint and the second condition is meant to be the product not the sum of the two cosines. In which case the problem and solution is appropriate for a multiple-choice question to be solved in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Yes! Also, it could be sum of $\cot$'s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show my attempts: I wrote down the system
\begin{align}
&\frac{s_1}{c_1}+\frac{s_2}{c_2}=4,\\
&c_1+c_2=1/5,\\
&c_1^2+s_1^2=1,\\
&c_2^2+s_2^2=1
\end{align}
solved with *Wolfram Mathematica* and obtained $8$ solution, but by symmetry they are only $4$. Excluded a complex solution, I have three solutions.
Substituted in
$$
\frac{\frac{s_1}{c_1}+\frac{s_2}{c_2}}{1-\frac{s_1s_2}{c_1c_2}}
$$
I get the three values
$$
(-1.47878, 0.0385584, 0.209877).
$$

Furthermore, if it's a multiple solution test, with proposed results $r_1,\ldots,r_n,$ then you can proceed backward: find the product of tangents as
$$
p=1-\frac{4}{r_i}
$$
then given sum $s$ of tangents and their product, find the values of tangents $t_1,t_2$ solving
$$
t^2-s t+p=0
$$
and finally calculate the sum of cosines as
$$
\cos(\arctan t_1)+\cos(\arctan t_2)
$$
that should give $1/5$ for a correct solution.

Comment: Thank you. Proving that something is wrong with it is enough for me :)

Comment: @VIVID, thank you, but you should probably not accept my answer

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: @VIVID because it's only an extended comment, and does not really provide an analytical solution